# Is it possible to set the width of a set of elements to add up to 100%?

Tags: css

Probably not the best title I've ever written, but I find it hard to formulate this question well. I'm working on a div that should cover 100% of the parent (could be body). This div should have a *variable number* of children, so every time the page is refreshed the children count can vary from one to ten, maybe more.

I want these children to all be **equally wide** and have a percentage width. So if there are five children, each child should have `width: 20%`. If there are two children, they should have `width: 50%`. I could do this with JavaScript, but I'd really prefer keeping all layout stuff in the css.

Is there a way to accomplish this without using tables?

Comment: Isn't a div containing some other divs really the same as a table row containing some columns? I know people usually avoid HTML tables, but the reasons are now historic. This is a real need however, and maybe one day we will have a weight CSS property. Hopefully.

Comment: So you're saying this can't be done without tables or JavaScript? Because I'll accept that as an answer if you're sure

Comment: Well, what I think you really need is support for 'weights'. That is how layout works for example on Android. Ignore this part if you are familiar with the platform, but essentially you define a screen in XML, and elements either have the size of their content, or the size of their container. When there are multiple elements in a container, its "layout_weight", as a ratio weighted against its siblings' determines how much space it will occupy. Now, this paradigm is slightly foreign to web design, but is in some ways more powerful and would be a nice incremental addition.

Comment: Tables are the only feature in HTML that come close, and yes you can `tableize` divs or any element from CSS, but they will still be tables and use the browser's table layout algorithms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display: table`, `display: table-cell`,  and `table-layout: fixed`.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/ZKXrM/

`table-layout: fixed` is to equally distribute the available width between any cells without an assigned width.

[This works in all modern browsers. It doesn't work in IE7.](http://caniuse.com/css-table) If you need this to work in IE7, either use JavaScript to polyfill, or use a real `<table>`.

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    display: table;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%;
}
.container > div {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px dashed red;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    ..
</div>​
```

Comment: It's been in the CSS2 spec since *forever*, but the lack of IE7 support means it's not as widely used as it otherwise would have been.

Comment: Screw IE7. Anybody who refuses to switch to a modern browser isn't welcome in my website anyway :-) This is the best way proposed to avoid table tags in my HTML and still accomplish what I'm going for so I'll accept the answer

Comment: I don't find it particularly useful that this enables me to write `<div><div/><div/></div>` instead of `<table><tr><td/><td/></tr></table>` but also needs a five-line CSS which negates any possible bandwidth savings. This is essentially CSS for turning divs into tables, with all their (dis)advantages.

Comment: @Péter Varga: Why are you talking about bandwidth? That's completely irrelevant; CSS is generally downloaded once and then cached. The benefit of `display: table` is that you don't have to use non-semantic (HTML) `<table>`s for layout purposes, instead you can use whatever HTML you should actually be using. It's the exact *opposite* of what you said: CSS for turning `div`s into `table`s with **none** of the disadvantages of a HTML `<table>`. Of course, you should still use `<table>` when it is the correct semantic choice, for example a table of data.

Answer (score 1):

You could define something like

```
div#contains2 div
{
    width: 50%;
}

div#contains3 div
{
    width: 33%;
}
```

and so on, then apply the appropriate class to the parent div.

That said, is there a good reason why you're avoiding a table, but trying to recreate how a table works? Sure, it may not be the absolute nicest "sleep-well-at-night" way to make a page, but if the table does the job how you want it doing, and you can't think of anything else that does, go with the table.

---

The bottom line is that you have essentially 3 options for automatic same-width columns:

- Tables, which do it out of the box and will work cross-browser with no major issues
- jQuery, which will probably work cross browser, provided the user has JS enabled
- CSS like I suggested above, which adds bloat to your CSS file, and fluff to your markup

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using tables for layout because there are numerous and valid reasons why that's frowned upon. I want to know that css **can't** help me before I resort to tables

Comment: Yes it's frowned upon, but going out of your way to make divs work like a table does is equally pointless - just being able to say "I don't use tables" isn't that good, when you actually have to say "I made divs work like tables because tables are like, universally pure evil"

Comment: It's not pointless if you avoid the chaos that is layout tables :P But otherwise I agree. I'm keeping tables a last resort and if you tell me it's necessary I'll believe you

Comment: In that case, yes, it's necessary - the only tag that works like a table for this is a table. You can do it with JS, you can use tables, or you can add fluff and bloat with the CSS I suggested - pick your poison :)

Comment: If you want to edit your answer to describe our conclusion I'll accept it. Otherwise I'll do it myself at a later point. Thanks for the help

Comment: Actually I am really interested in valid reasons against HTML tables, apart from the fact that they have been heavily misused historically. But then again, every technology can be misused.

Comment: Semantics - using a `<table>` tag implies that it contains tabular data. When it's actually only being used for layout, the tag has no semantic meaning.

Answer (score -1):

You can divide the total width (100%) into the number of items (X). So W = 100/X and W=Width.

Comment: Well yes, obviously, but how would that look like in CSS?

Comment: In jQuery: `var X = $("div").length; var W = 100/X;`  `$("div").css({width: W});`

Comment: So resorting to JavaScript. In my question I specify that I can do this using JavaScript, but I'm looking for an answer to how to do this using css only

Comment: Oh, sorry. I'm afraid you can't, I tried to do so some weeks ago and it was impossible :S Only tables, jquery or JS.

Comment: You can do this in CSS, but it won't be as elegant as it could. It will involve something like `width:expression(document.getElementById('container').width / document.getElementsByClassName('element').length);`, essentially JavaScript in CSS...

Comment: What the hell, can you use JavaScript inside a stylesheet?